# phpBB rewrite rules and php parser rules conflicting on nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Guys I am so bad at this nginx rewrite rules. Sad thing is that nginx is sooooo lightening fast that I cannot also quit using it.

Please help me.

I have installed SEO urls on the forum.
But i am unable to control the php files and the SEO urls both together.

If i open the **SEO urls** then php parser stops working and i can download the php source files instead.
/forum/compare-cameras-support-f1/

BUT if i open **php URLs** in format below they work fine.
/forum/viewforum.php?f=1

I have spent hours trying to make both work but have just given up.

```
    location ^~ /forum/ {
            # forum will run separate

            # rewrite rules for forum
            rewrite ^/(.*)-f([0-9]*)/(.*)-t([0-9]*)-s([0-9]*).html  /forum/viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$5&$query_string break;
            rewrite ^/(.*)-f([0-9]*)/(.*)-t([0-9]*).html            /forum/viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&$query_string break;
            rewrite ^/(.*)-f([0-9]*)/index-s([0-9]*).html           /forum/viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$3&$query_string break;
            rewrite ^/(.*)-f([0-9]*)/                               /forum/viewforum.php?f=$2&$query_string break;
            rewrite ^/(.*)-f([0-9]*)                                /forum/viewforum.php?f=$2&$query_string break;

            # app rewrite rules for the INSTALLATION
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/install/app.php?$query_string;

            location ~ \.php$ {

                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }
    }
```

Please help

Comment: Try using `last` rather than `break` in your `rewrite` rules. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you soooo much.

Comment: Do you wanna write it as an answer so that i can accept it ( _if it matters_ ). Thanks for your valued time.